# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, nominatim

I am creating a certain function that can give me information regarding the ISS (International Space Station) and a given location (in decimal coordinates) that can vary, depending on the input. But when I use this:

```
print(ubicacion.raw['address']['country'],",",ubicacion.raw['address']['city'])
```

It works, but for certain countries, and for example when I try with the coordinates Canberra, it displays the following info:

> Corinna Street, Phillip, District of Woden Valley, Australian Capital Territory, 2606, Australia

and since it doesn't provide the city, when I use the key `"city"`, I obviously get an error, since it doesn't exist in that list.

So one solution that I got in my mind was that since at least I will always get the country, maybe I could use another function, that based on the country, I could get the capital city, which is the one I need and it exists, I used `"CountryInfo"` (`from countryinfo import CountryInfo`). The problem is, that when I try to use it, I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to

I have already searched for similar questions and many people suggest to specify the encoding, but it seems to not work with `geopy`. since I tried this:

```
countryinfo=CountryInfo(country,encoding="utf8")
```

and I got this error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Referenced from: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Countryinfo-package-charmap-error

from @snippsat's answer Sep-14-2018, 11:37 AM

Open ***countryinfo.py*** in ..Lib\site-packages\countryinfo folder.
Change the line to:

```
country_info = json.load(open(file_path, encoding='utf-8'))
```

It works for me.

Comment: Works. So why Python does not recognize utf-8 at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

```
from countryinfo import CountryInfo

country = CountryInfo('Singapore')
country.capital()
# returns string
'Singapore'
```

country.capital() will get you the capital in a string format

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me, I get the error from the title.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Try to at least read my post before commenting the first thing that appears in Google when you search for "CountryInfo Python"...