# Word count of Markdown cells in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to perform a word count of only markdown cells in Jupyter Notebook, and if possible within the notebook itself? Thanks

**Edit**: Appears that doing it within the notebook is rather complicated, I'm happy with just with an external solution

Comment: Looks like it won't be straightforward: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3101

Comment: @Chris ah, never mind it being within the notebook then. Is there an external method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Jupyter notebook is just a JSON file (`.ipynb`-file). We could parse this JSON using Python and filter for cells with `'cell_type': 'markdown'` and reduce the `source` content to a word count.

For parsing a JSON file we can just use the builtin [JSON encover/decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library as follows.

```py
import json

with open('test.ipynb') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data)
```

whereby `test.ipynb` is a Jupyter notebook with two code cells and two markdown cells. The output of `data` is as follows.

```py
{
   "cells":[
      {
         "cell_type":"markdown",
         "metadata":{
            
         },
         "source":[
            "# This is a markdown file\n",
            "Hello World"
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell_type":"code",
         "execution_count":2,
         "metadata":{
            
         },
         "outputs":[
            {
               "name":"stdout",
               "output_type":"stream",
               "text":[
                  "Hello World\n"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "source":[
            "print(\"Hello World\")"
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell_type":"code",
         "execution_count":3,
         "metadata":{
            
         },
         "outputs":[
            {
               "name":"stdout",
               "output_type":"stream",
               "text":[
                  "Hello World 2\n"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "source":[
            "print(\"Hello World 2\")"
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell_type":"markdown",
         "metadata":{
            
         },
         "source":[
            "## More markdown\n",
            "hello"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "metadata":{
      "interpreter":{
         "hash":"e7370f93d1d0cde622a1f8e1c04877d8463912d04d973331ad4851f04de6915a"
      },
      "kernelspec":{
         "display_name":"Python 3.10.2 64-bit",
         "language":"python",
         "name":"python3"
      },
      "language_info":{
         "codemirror_mode":{
            "name":"ipython",
            "version":3
         },
         "file_extension":".py",
         "mimetype":"text/x-python",
         "name":"python",
         "nbconvert_exporter":"python",
         "pygments_lexer":"ipython3",
         "version":"3.10.2"
      },
      "orig_nbformat":4
   },
   "nbformat":4,
   "nbformat_minor":2
}
```

A possible function, that retrieves all strings from `source` mappings from cells of type `markdown` could look as follows.

```py
wordCount = 0
for each in data['cells']:
    cellType = each['cell_type']
    if cellType == "markdown":
        content = each['source']
        for line in content:
            temp = [word for word in line.split() if "#" not in word] # we might need to filter for more markdown keywords here
            wordCount = wordCount + len(temp)
            
print(wordCount)
```

Comment: This is brilliant thanks, just to note that for some files I had to add `encoding='utf-8'` into the 'open' function (`with open('test.ipynb', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:`) as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447543/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81-in-position-49-chara). Seems to be something to do with certain symbols used inside ipynb files perhaps.

Comment: @tim-hy good catch! There could be all kind of characters, so it is better to provide utf-8!

Comment: Much of the initial file opening and parsing to get the markdown content could be replaced with the use a notebook-specific handler, `nbformat` that comes with Jupyter. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/delete-all-code-cells-except-markdown-text/3072/2?u=fomightez) as a guide.

Comment: @Wayne I haven't heard of that method. It looks pretty neat, though!

Comment: For trying nbformat out conveniently, you use it in notebooks are in script in launches via MyBinder, such as the top ones [here](https://jupyter.org/try).